# Unable to found org.hibernate.service.jdbc.dialect.internal.StandardDialectResolver in Hibernate 5.4

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-5.x

I am migrating project from Hibernate 4.2.20 to Hibernate 5.4 version, but I am unable to find the `org.hibernate.service.jdbc.dialect.internal.StandardDialectResolver`.

In fact the package `org.hibernate.service.jdbc.XXXXXX` is also *not available* in `hibernate-core-5.4.0.final.jar`

With previous version class `StandardDialectResolver` was there but with 5.4 version the class does not exists.

So anyone knows how to resolve this problem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you check org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.StandardDialectResolver

Answer (score -1):

The site findjar.com shows you the jars a particular class can be found in on major maven repositories.  The class you mention looks like it is in hibernate-core through

```
[JAR] hibernate-core-4.2.6.Final.jar in org/hibernate/hibernate-core/4.2.6.Final
[JAR] hibernate-core-4.2.7.Final.jar in org/hibernate/hibernate-core/4.2.7.Final
[JAR] hibernate-core-4.2.7.SP1.jar in org/hibernate/hibernate-core/4.2.7.SP1
[JAR] hibernate-core-4.2.8.Final.jar in org/hibernate/hibernate-core/4.2.8.Final
[JAR] hibernate-core-4.2.9.Final.jar in org/hibernate/hibernate-core/4.2.9.Final
```

After that, it looks like projects using it incorporated the class directly in their own jars.  Here are a few instances of that:

```
[JAR] hibernate-core-4.1.3.Final-patched-play-1.3.0.jar in com/google/code/maven-play-plugin/org/hibernate/hibernate-core/4.1.3.Final-patched-play-1.3.0
[JAR] hibernate-core-4.2.15.Final-patched-play-1.3.0.jar in com/google/code/maven-play-plugin/org/hibernate/hibernate-core/4.2.15.Final-patched-play-1.3.0
[JAR] hibernate-core-4.2.19.Final-patched-play-1.3.2.jar in com/google/code/maven-play-plugin/org/hibernate/hibernate-core/4.2.19.Final-patched-play-1.3.2
[JAR] querydsl-jpa-2.7.1-apt-hibernate-one-jar.jar in com/mysema/querydsl/querydsl-jpa/2.7.1
```

Comment: I want that in Hibernate 5.4 not 4.X